# Copy-paste notepad++ text with formatting, keeping linebreaks

Tags: notepad++, microsoft-onenote

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475790/copy-notepad-text-with-formatting

Let's say I put the below in Notepad++.
If I do the above steps (Nppexport -->
Copy all formats to clipboard), then when copied in Microsoft Word, it works nice, but for OneNote it ignores lines-breaks.
So if I want to copy in OneNote, I have to first copy in Word, and from there to OneNote.

Is there any way to paste in Onenote with default good formatting?

```
first_line
second-line
```

I am using Notepad++ v7.9.1. 64-bit, Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Have you checked the HTML code NPPExport generates?

Comment: What kind of linebreak do you have in irginal file? `\n` or `\r\n`? Try to change then to `\r\n`

Comment: @Robert yes, same result with HTML

Comment: @Toto replaced in the Replace menu regex search, same issue. Also tried Edit/EOL Conversion to Mac, UNIX, Windows, same issue

Comment: This seems to be a known problem: https://github.com/chcg/NPP_ExportPlugin/issues/18 OneNote does not seem to recognize the `white-space: pre` style and therefore does not import the line breaks correctly.